# How to merge .CSV files by adding a columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell

have a directory with many .CSV which I would like to merge in a single matrix and add the file name as additional header in the first line.

```
.CSV file A:

header 1, header 2
value 1, value 2


.CSV file B:

header 3, header 4,
value 3, value 4


Merged .CSV:

filename A, filename A, filename B, filename B
header 1, header 2, header 3, header 4,
value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

I guess I  have to explain in more detail!

.CSV files are not identical. That means all have the same number of columns but the number of rows can differ.

```
A.csv
H1,H2
1,2
3,4

B.csv
H1,H2
5,6

MERGED.csv
A,A,B,B
H1,H2,H1,H2
1,2,5,6
3,4,,
```

Comment: You tagged this as a bash question. Is there a reason you need to use bash? This is very simple with python or R.

Comment: Wanted to run in on my NAS and bash seemed to me to be the easiest way. How would be the way to do it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to merge the files, the command could be as simple as

```
paste -d , A B
```

Merged result would be

```
header 1,header 2,header 3,header 4
value 1,value 2,value 3,value 4
```

Since you also want to insert file name as additional header now, the input files require extra preparation. Here is my solution.

```
prepareCsvFile() {
    sed "1p" "$1" | sed "1s/[^,]*/filename $1/g"
}
paste -d , <(prepareCsvFile A) <(prepareCsvFile B)
```

The prepareCsvFile function duplicates the first line in CSV file, and replaces all header names between `,` to be filename in the new first line.

Comment: Thanks!

`paste -d , A B` is adding a line break after header 2 and value 2. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What is your shell version? I tried on my `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0)` and `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)` and didn't see line break with paste.